# Compare application configuration tables, ignore some field+string replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, compare

Recently I joined a team that is responsible for the configuration and maintenance of a third party application that comes with core features "off-the-shelf". Over the last few years there has been *lots* of configuration and macro programming to meet our organisations requirements.

A team of 3 people work full-time on adding parsing scripts (to read import files) and subroutines using a built-in macro language, and also configuring barcode labels, user screens, menus, reports, workflows etc. This configuration and programming is all stored in the SQL Server database, in around 200+ tables specific to this application (SUBROUTINE, FORMULATION_TEMP, STORAGE_CONDITIONS, PARSING_SCRIPTS, FOLDER_TEMPLATE etc.).

The application only provides bare-bones change management support, so each time we work on additional features we carefully keep track of each change in a spreadsheet so we know what to deploy to the acceptation and production environments.

This has of course proven to be insufficient, as sometimes there is a single missing piece of configuration, there are critical bugfixes on production not reverted to development etc. As a result, there now are many subtle differences between development and production.

To make things more complicated, certain tables contain macro code which is stored in a single row using ascii text "& #10;" as line breaks, so to see the real differences you still have to open it in the editor. Also, almost all tables have two fields CHANGED_BY/CHANGED_ON which are not important, because the build-in change management tool overwrites these values with current date and user when importing(!).

**My question:**
Is there a tool to compare the data of two databases for a specific set of tables, while also ignoring certain fields in those tables (the structure is the same)? And, ideally, also while doing some string replace beforehand on some fields?

We already had Redgate SQL-Compare but we bought a license only to compare structure, not data. We could buy a license but I doubt this will give a workable compare. We are thinking about making our own custom compare utility.

Comment: Could you give an example of what kind of comparison you want to do? Are you trying to find tables of similar structure to compare to each other?  Anything can be looped through and automated, that much I know.

Comment: What is it about SQL Data Compare that wouldn't be workable in your example?